# how to add a two column description before table of contents in rmarkdown pdf or word document

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am going to create a cover page like below
[image]
I add logo, title, date and table of contents. However, I am not sure how to create the section marked in red. I would appreciate any help with this.

````
---
title: |
  ![](/path/to/logo.png)  \
  \
  my title my title my title


date: "01/01/2000"

output:
  word_document:
    toc: true


header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \usepackage{multicol}
  - \usepackage{lscape}
  - \usepackage{fontspec}    
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE
)
```
## chapter1
## chapter2
````

Answer (score 0):

Add a class option at the top and then use proper format at the bottom.

I got this code to produce the image below which was rendered in RMarkdown:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
date: "2023-04-04"
classoption:
- twocolumn
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown


# Two columns



:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column width="40%"}

advisors  

Abcd Efg  

Opq Rst  

:::
::: {.column width="60%"}
students:  

Abcd Efg  

Opq Rst  

:::
::::::::::::::
````

[image]